# Emailing smtp with Python error

Tags: python, email, smtp

I can't figure out why this isn't working.  I'm trying to send an email from my school email address with this code I got online.  The same code works for sending from my GMail address.  Does anyone know what this error means?  The error occurs after waiting for about one and a half minutes.

```
import smtplib

FROMADDR = "FROM_EMAIL"
LOGIN    = "USERNAME"
PASSWORD = "PASSWORD"
TOADDRS  = ["TO_EMAIL"]
SUBJECT  = "Test"

msg = ("From: %s\r\nTo: %s\r\nSubject: %s\r\n\r\n"
    % (FROMADDR, ", ".join(TOADDRS), SUBJECT) )
msg += "some text\r\n"

server = smtplib.SMTP('OUTGOING_SMTP', 465)
server.set_debuglevel(1)
server.ehlo()
server.starttls()
server.login(LOGIN, PASSWORD)
server.sendmail(FROMADDR, TOADDRS, msg)
server.quit()
```

And here's the error I get:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last): 
      File "emailer.py", line 13, in 
    server = smtplib.SMTP('OUTGOING_SMTP', 465)
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/smtplib.py", line 239, in init
    (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/smtplib.py", line 295, in connect
    self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/smtplib.py", line 273, in _get_socket
    return socket.create_connection((port, host), timeout)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/socket.py", line 514, in create_connection
    raise error, msg
socket.error: [Errno 60] Operation timed out
```

Comment: Have you checked if the outgoing smtp port is blocked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's likely that your school's SMTP server does not permit outside access to port 587. Gmail does, and requires authentication to ensure that you are who you say you are (and so that spammers can't send email appearing to be *from* you unless they know your password). Your school may have chosen to set up their mail server so that only connections from *within* the school can send mail in this way.

Comment: Thank you. I tried with port 465, and now I don't even get an error, it just stays until I ctrl+c for a keyboard interrupt. I can't fit the resulting error message because it won't fit in this comment.  Is it appropriate to start another question with this new information?

Comment: @jakecar: What prompted you to try port 465? That's SMTP over SSL, and unless you *know* that your school supports that protocol, they probably don't.

Comment: You're correct, I just realized that my school uses SSL :X...I'm gonna go ahead and guess that I need to add some special code to deal with the SSL?

Comment: @jakecar: Yes, you will. You might be best off at this point opening a new question such as "How can I connect to a mail server using SMTP over SSL using Python?"